# Block diagonalization of a symmetric square boolean matrix

Tags: algorithms, block-matrices

I have a symmetric square matrix with elements from $\{0,1\}$. How can I block diagonalize it only swapping lines and columns or detect it's not possible?

Comment: Do you require swapping rows and columns simultaneously? If the matrix, for example, is the adjacency matrix of a graph, then this is necessary.

Comment: @user60079 Yes, it's adjacency matrix of a graph. I forgot to add that it's symmetric.

Comment: Then this means the graph is undirected, so it is block diagonisable if and only if the graph is multipartite.

Comment: @user60079 The thing is that I thought would be possible to block diagonalize the matrix first, it would give those parts as blocks. Maybe there's some algorithm for such matrices, easier than walking through the graph?

Comment: Sorry, I think I used the wrong word. I meant the graph is disconnected, not multipartite. Let me think of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work, if you are looking for an algorithm:

1. Start with a vertex.
2. Find all its neighbors $N_1$, and delete the vertex itself.
3. Find all the neigbors $N_2$ of the neigbors, and delete the neigbors $N_1$.
4. Continue the progress until no more neigbors are found.
5. Check if there is any vertex remained. If yes, then the matrix is block diagonisable; otherwise is not.